# Safari ignoring text:decoration:underline;

Tags: css, safari, underline, text-decorations

I cant get underline to work in safari, it seems to be picking up the default link style of underline none, instead of the css below.

Any ideas what could be causing this?

```
div.header .container .accountPannel .top a.alias { color:#fff; font-size:10px; float:left; text-decoration:underline !important; max-width:108px; overflow:hidden;}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Would need more info. Only thing to get from there is it could possibly be the overflow hiding the underline.

Answer (score 2):

The decorations are **not** propagated to floated or absolutely positioned descendants, or to descendant inline tables or inline blocks.

Answer (score 1):

I am going to assume here that you have made a user stylesheet for Safari that turns the underlines for links off, because Safari doesn't have a program setting for those underlines.

So, what has probably happened is that you have

```
text-decoration: none !important;
```

in your user stylesheet.
And user stylesheets always override document stylesheets. So no matter if you put `!important` in the document or not, the user style will always be in effect.

Solution: edit your user stylesheet to read simply

```
text-decoration: none;
```

and then it *can* be overridden by document styles.